# 'set next statement' command not working on a PCL project of Xamarin in Android

Tags: xamarin

I am not able to do "Set Next statement" nor am able to "change any value of any variable" in runtime, via Visual studio 2013" for a "PCL" projects "cs" file of Xamarin. Am i missing any setting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a security restriction for mobile runtimes, especially on iOS, that does not allow you to inject interpreted code or modify execution at runtime. That is the reason why even on PCL layer you can't use these debugger features.

Comment: Thanks michael, but i am using Android. i will update the question accordingly.